# Getting a function's name when the function is contained inside a TypeScript namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, namespaces

I would like to be able to obtain a TypeScript function's own name from within the function. I have read through the [Function: name documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name), but the following code does not work as expected.

Here is a simple test code ([link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?alwaysStrict=false&target=2&ssl=12&ssc=52&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMGBeGAKAlGgfDAbwFgAoGcmAJwFMoFKx4lgA6MAQwFtqBuUgX1KkO3CAAd2wajAByAZUKkKMagA8xISrFCRYiZGkw5U%20YmWUUadBrLkt9rEbyUVBJN6R0QQAG2osfEABzDAdsLB4YAHoomABRdWpgWBAEKDE0gC4YAHIHHM9wbz8A4Ix5e2ZwyJj4xOSYVPSs3Ir8oA))

```
const func = () => {
    return func.name;
}

namespace NS {
    export const func = () => {
        return NS.func.name;
    }
}

console.log(func()); // Expect output: 'func'
console.log(NS.func()); // Expect output: 'NS.func'
```

The actual output of the code is

```
'func'
''
```

Seems like if a function is contained within a namespace, the Function.name property is set to an empty string.

Is there a clever way to get around this?

Comment: Use a proper object method? `const NS = { func() { return NS.func.name } };`. But you'll never get the `NS` as part of the name, no.

Comment: Relying on the function name is probably a code smell. It's mostly there for debugging purposes - having code actually require a specific name seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: when you create the func that way, you are creating it anonymously, that's why it returns a empty string